# AspectJ + Perf4J + Spring and @Profiled annotation?

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, perf4j

I can't get AspectJ to work at all, and I have ran out of ideas after following 10 different tutorials.

Here is what I am trying to do...

I have a Spring application. It uses Spring, Perf4J, and Now Aspect(if it ever works!) and I want to use @Profiled("some tag here") at the tog of my public method. That is it, nothing too fancy.

Here is the code I am trying to run :

```
@Override
@Profiled(tag = "MainClass" + ".runMethod", logFailuresSeparately = true)
public Collection<Throwable> runMethod() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Running a simple method that I want timings for.");

}
```

Here are my POM dependencies used in maven to get everything to set up.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring (includes spring-aop)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ (required spring-aop dependency) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- LOG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${perf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the aspect beans file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:include name="timingAspect"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<!--<context:load-time-weaver/> -->

<!--  The perf4j aspect -->
<bean id="timingAspect" class="org.perf4j.log4j.aop.TimingAspect"/>
```

Here is how I bring that XML beans file in (within the spring application context file) :

```
<import resource="aspectBeans.xml" />
```

Now, the application compiles, it runs, and it prints my System.out.println line, but I am seeing absolutely nothing related to timing.

Comment: You have a complex mix of technologies there. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including Maven build on GitHub. The snippets here are IMO not enough to analyse the situation.

Comment: Deleted :)

I am unable to recreate this problem as an MCVE as that would mean building a whole new app with perf4j etc, and I can't even get the @Profiled tag to work on this established application - I will end up spending all week trying to learn the whole framework - which I intend doing - but I need to get this issue fixed first as it is for work.

Comment: Is it so difficult to extract a minimal example exposing the problem from your existing project? You are a software developer, I guess. Just copy the directory, open it, strip off everything step by step until there is nothing left to strip off, but the problem still remains. Sounds straightforward to me. You might even learn something about your problem along the way.

Comment: I am actually not a developer - Kind of got thrown in the deep end here with a bunch of work that normally isn't my job - I am totally down to learn this stuff - but I need this to be working today or I will be in serious trouble - and I just don't have all that time available to study this - was hoping getting a fix would be fairly straight forward. Unfortunately it looks like that is not the case. I have followed 12 different tutorials for this now, and can't get any of them to work. I will leave this open a little while longer and see if anyone can help - but I might have to close it out.